# IF inside VALUES into an INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I begin using triggers and I have differents values to insert according to NEW.lettre2. So I would like to know the good quivalent (only in SQL, no php) for :

```
...
BEGIN
INSERT INTO newsfeed(lettre1) 
VALUES (IF(NEW.lettre2='a','b','c') );
END |
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the help of a sub select :

```
INSERT INTO newsfeed(lettre1) 
VALUES (SELECT IF(NEW.lettre2='a','b','c') AS col1 );
```

Comment: Hi, MySQL returns : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...

Comment: Check the synthax in your context and keep the idea ... Post more details if you want more help .